# XML retornado por web service com erro de codificação

Tags: php, xml, codificação-de-caracteres, codificação-de-conteúdo

Olá, tenho um XML que retorna de um webservice com erros de codificação, no *encoding* do XML está como UTF-8 porém não exibe acentos corretamente e não consigo detectar qual codificação correta a mesma deve estar. Não tenho informação nenhuma de como está armazenado no banco de dados original ou qualquer outra do tipo, apenas tenho retorno do mesmo. aqui um exemplo de como recebo o XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<title>Muitos cientistas intrØpidos se aventura no coraĿªo dos dois vulcıes mais explosivos do planeta</title>
</test>
```

Como posso converter/detectar a codificação e corrigir os erros de acento?
Existe alguma maneira de convertes este caracteres depois de gerador pelo webservice ou essa correção só pode ser feita no próprio webservice uma vez que o XML já foi gerado?

Obs: já tentei funções como `iconv`, `utf8_decode`, `mb_convert_encode`.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: já tentou uma solução usando `iconv()`? Aqui tem um exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7980354/1001109

Comment: Sim, amigao so ler a descricao da pergunta.

Comment: Seria interessante ao AP, que os negativos fossem explicados, para que ele possa melhorar a pergunta...

Comment: @rafaelphp  coloque o código que pega esse XML...

Comment: O correto neste caso é corrigir no XML no origem

Comment: nao tenho acesso ao ws. como disse na pergunta.

Comment: Será que não está misturando algo do xml ou algum outro script e na hora do output esta conflitando? Tem certeza que é no WS? Poderia colocar o código do funcionamento?

Comment: ja tentei varias maneiras, curl, file_get_contents etc ate memso ao acessar a url pelo browser vem com o mesmo xml

Comment: Já tentou o utf8-encode ?!? Verificou o encode dos arquivos? *(pouco provável) Já deu mb_detect_encoding() para descobrir o encoding que está chegando ?

Comment: Só para entender você está usando um serviço externo que retorna a string quebrada no xml certo ?

Comment: O ideal é você fornecer o endpoint desse xml para olharmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um par de erros típicos que levam a este tipo de situações.
Neste caso houve uma conversão para utf8 de um latin1 mas indicando que era outra coisa (neste caso ISO6937).

**Solução com Iconv**:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ISO6937 x.xml | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8
```

**Explicação** : Mas afinal como chegar e este milagroso "ISO6937" ?:
Inverter o processo com todos os encodings conhecidos e ver os que acertaram!

**1:**  quais os encodes existentes conhecidos pelo iconv? -- `iconv -l`

**2:** inverter o processo para todos (criando um ficheiro `_encode`):

```
for a in `iconv -l | cut -d/ -f 1 `
do   
   iconv -c -f utf8 -t $a x.xml | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 > _$a
done
```

**3:** procurar oss que produziram o resultado pretendido (e escolher um):

```
$ grep -l 'intrépido.*coração.*vulcões' _* 
_ANSI_X3.110
_ANSI_X3.110-1983
_CSA_T500
_CSISO103T618BIT
_CSISO90
_CSISO99NAPLPS
_ISO6937
_ISO_6937
_ISO_6937:1992
....
```

alguns destes nomes são alias do mesmo chaset

Answer (score 6):

Nesse caso uma solução seria, você fazer um mapa com os padrões do `encoding` retornados, e substituí-los, exemplo :

```
<?php 
$arr = array("Ø" => "é","Ŀ" => "ç","ª" => "ã", "ı" => "õ"); 
$word = "Muitos cientistas intrØpidos se aventura no coraĿªo dos dois vulcıes mais explosivos do planeta"; 
echo strtr($word,$arr); 
?>
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Vou36E)

Comment: Acho que deveria ser `"Ø" => "é"`.

Comment: É uma palavra bem incomum de se usar, mas eu pessoalmente já a conhecia de algumas narrações de RPG: https://www.dicio.com.br/intrepido/

Comment: Dei -1 pois não está resolvendo o problema, e sim sugerindo algo que vai causar muito problemas futuros na rotina que trata os dados.

Comment: @jlHertel pelo contrário no caso de ele não ter acesso ao ws a única solução é tratar os dados recebidos...  E minha respota é uma das soluções possíveis... Aliás dentro das repostas apresentadas é a única solução... Todos falam o por que de não dar mas nínguem ofereceu nenhuma solução real

Comment: Ok, pode ser uma solução, mas se algum dia qualquer caractere novo aparecer vai exigir uma manutenção na rotina. Logo, isto se torna insustentável.

Comment: Em qual ponto da pergunta, há uma referência sobre manutenção posterior ? Quer dizer então que se um problema desse aparece, você não busca uma solução ? Você vai ficar esperando ter acesso ao ws ? Eu penso em como solucionar e não em apontar onde está o problema, isso já foi apontado pelo próprio AP... Seu negativo é injusto

Comment: Obrigado @MagicHat voce tem razao pelo que vi nos comentarios, e creio que voce propos algo para solucionar (leu a pergunta) e apresentou seu parecer. Creio que para isso a unica solucao que tenho, mesmo que tenha mais manutencoes em um futuro proximo.

Comment: O mais difícil (e nem tanto) é vc montar o mapa, ou seja se vc conseguir todos os caracteres que o ws te manda de forma incorreta e identificar qual o caractere correto fica até fácil, entretanto se vc precisar entregar um xml válido vc terá que depois das alterações gerar um novo xml válido, mas num é um bicho de 7 cabeças...

Comment: Dada a atual situação, é a melhor alternativa. E, na realidade, nem são tantos caracteres assim para impossibilitar de montar uma mapeamento. Vai ser chato, mas vai resolver um problema que, segundo o autor, não pode ser resolvido na fonte.

Answer (score 4):

Você já está recebendo o dado incorretamente e portanto, será praticamente impossível *detectar* a codificação que a informação está chegando.

Minha recomendação é que você verifique a rotina que está gerando o XML e realize uma correção nela.

Alguns detalhes importantes: O padrão do XML define a codificação dos caracteres em seu cabeçalho com o `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.
A rotina que irá ler estes dados deve respeitar esta codificação e utilizá-la para ler os dados.
Caso a codificação seja diferente da informada no arquivo, o XML está inválido.

Comment: creio que vc confirmou o que estava pensando. e esse tipo de problema nao tem como corrigir depois de o xml ser gerado a solucao eh alterar no ws, porem nao tenho acesso. se nao tem solucao resolvido esta. obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Quando tive este problema, o arquivo que gerava o meu XML estava salvo com a codificação ANSI
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
, bastou eu alterar o formato do arquivo para UTF-8 e funcionou.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: nao tenho aceso ao ws que retorna o xml esses dados estao vindo dessa maneira, a pergunta eh como tratar a codificacao depois de gerado

Comment: Perdão, entendi que você era o fornecedor do conteúdo do XML, neste caso apenas por substituição mesmo, como foi sugerido por @magichat:

echo strtr($xml->saveXML(), array("Ø" => "é","Ŀ" => "ç","ª" => "ã", "ı" => "õ")); 

Porém se seu XML realmente precisar dos caracteres especiais

<title>Em 1962, Armstrong tornou-se astronauta e quatro anos depois participou pela 1ª vez numa missão espacial</title>

Assim, o treixo _1ª_ não esta incorreto, mas ficará como _1ã_, então procure  combinar possíveis silabas, tais como "Ŀª" => "ça"

Comment: Obrigado pela sugerencia.